# Excel function using value from previous function not working

Tags: excel, function

I'm trying to use the following max function by the group in column A. The value I want in C is the max entry of each group in column B. When column B is normal numbers, this function works. However, I would like column B to be populated by the results of a different function (in this case an `=IF` function that successfully returns a number). When I do this, I get 0's.

in column C:  `=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$5=C2,$B$2:$B$5))`

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Group 1 | 5 | 5 |
| Group 1 | 4 | 5 |
| Group 2 | 6 | 7 |
| Group 2 | 7 | 7 |

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Group 1 | `=IF(...)` | 0 |
| Group 1 | `=IF(...)` | 0 |
| Group 2 | `=IF(...)` | 0 |
| Group 2 | `=IF(...)` | 0 |

Any idea what could be going on? Please let me know if I can provide anything additional to help explain.

Thank you!
Reese

Comment: What is the if?  My guess is that you are putting the numbers in as strings: ie you wrap them in `""`.

Comment: `$A$2:$A$5` is either "Group 1" or "Group 2". `C2` is "5", the two are never equal... What is your expected outcome, exactly?

Comment: @ScottCraner bingo. I feel so dumb. Here's my actual code. I had quotes around the numbers for some reason. Thank you! =IF(AND(S516<>T516,S516<>0),"1","0")

Comment: @dogman By the fact that I could "guess" the issue should let you know you are not alone in that mistake.  I have answered two others just today with the same issue.